# Spring boot Authenticate Rest API using Google OAuth2 and how to test using Postman

Tags: spring-boot, rest, postman, google-oauth, spring-security-oauth2

I have created the Spring boot Rest API and authenticating using Google OAuth2.

I am testing GET API using browser it is working fine. However, I need to test POST api, i am using POSTMAN and getting unwired HTML response.

pom.xml -------- included dependency.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Created Config-------------

```
public class OAuthConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {    
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().antMatcher("/**")
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/")
    .permitAll()
    .anyRequest()
    .authenticated().and().oauth2Login().and().oauth2Client();
    }
    }

=========================

    @GetMapping(value = "/hello", produces = "application/json")
    public Principal getHello(Principal principal) {
    return principal;
    }
```

This rest point is working fine with browser after authenticating using gmail user and password. Principal render the JOSN object on Browser. after hitting url http:localhost:8081/hello
"idToken":{
               "tokenValue":
However, It is not working with POSTMAN.

Please someone help me to test POST API using POSTMAN.

Comment: "It is not working" is too general. Which are the values you are setting in Postman? Headers?, Are you getting a 4XX, a 5XX or something else.Remove the pom and java snippets since your problem is postman not spring

Comment: i am putting in Header - Authorization and Bearer ya29.a0Adw1xeWkUW69-XXXXXXX Also i am getting Status 200 OK.

Comment: I am getting response as HTML like

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Forwarding ...</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

Comment: The point was to post all the information that you are feeding into postman. If you got status 200 then it succeeded

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue and I just solved it. Hope this will also work for you. I tried to get some infos from spring security samples, and I think it is helpful: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/oauth2/resource-server/hello-security
I guess you need to add this line in your code, though I don't excatly know why it works yet.

```
.oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2.jwt(withDefaults()))
```

Here is my code modified and works for me now on postman:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig {
    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri}")
    String jwkSetUri;

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.authorizeHttpRequests(
                        auth -> {
                        auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
                        }
                ).oauth2Login(withDefaults())
                .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2.jwt(withDefaults()));
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri(this.jwkSetUri).build();
    }
}
```

in application.properties:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-id=<your-id>
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-secret=<your-secret>
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set- uri=https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs
```